# How to extract coordinates from the url to center google maps?

Tags: php, google-maps

I need to extract the coordinates from the url and use it to center the map. The following is the code I use now. But when I use this code, the map doesn't load at all.

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
center:  new google.maps.LatLng(<?php $_GET['curlat']?> , <?php $_GET['curlng']?>),
zoom: 12,
mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
});
```

While if I pass the coordinates like the following,  it's working perfect

```
center:  new google.maps.LatLng(13.964711, 76.325325),
```

Evidently, the error is in the above line of code.
What am I doing wrong in extracting the url and passing the value?

Comment: Can you show the full URL (request) from which you are trying to extract the location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to echo the output :

```
ap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
center:  new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $_GET['curlat'] .",". $_GET['curlng'];?>),
zoom: 12,
mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it'll work if you actually print the variable !

```
    <?php echo $_GET['curlat']?>
```